# Passing variable to HTML output and then into a scriptlet

Tags: html, google-apps-script, web-applications

**Code.gs**

```
function doPost(e) {
    ...
    template.data += getCustomerData + "<br>";
}
return template.evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
```

**index.html**

```
...
<?= data ?>
```

The code shown does display the correct values.  However, it doesn't translate `<br>` into HTML. I'm not sure why it isn't working since `template.evaluate()` is supposed to return an `HtmlOutput` object.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default the strings are sanitized, converting special characters to their HTML encoded equivalents (such as < becoming &lt;).

When outputting HTML you must use <?!= to avoid sanitizing the data.

`<?!= data ?>`

See the details on standard & force-printing scriptlets here:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#standard_scriptlets

Comment: This does set the data, however, it is limited in that the data needs to be formatted previously (unless its something simple like a string or number). For a more comprehensive way to pass a server variable to the client html, see this answer: I made an answer regarding this here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38314034/2213940